# html entities privatemsg token

Tags: tokens, privatemsg

I am using the [privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module to send messages and mails with questions about plants. The subject is automatically filled in with the token of a node title, which is always a plantname. They always have **2 single quotes** in their names and that is turned into ' when it comes in the subject field of the private message.

What can I do about that?

Answer (score 0):

You may implement this: [hook_privatemsg_message_presave_alter](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21privatemsg%21privatemsg.api.php/function/hook_privatemsg_message_presave_alter/7) in you custom module and change the message's subject as you like.

Here is a code sample:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_privatemsg_message_presave_alter().
 */
function your_module_privatemsg_message_presave_alter(&$message) {
  // dsm($message); print out the $message contents
  $message->subject = "$message->subject"; // use single or double quotes
}
```

Tip: [strip quotes from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228282/how-do-i-remove-quotes-from-a-string)